# How To add a min and max length verification to a numbers field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, input

I have the code for a number field:

```
<label for="Phone">Phone Number</label><br/>
<input id="Phone" name="Phone"class="form-control" type="tel"      pattern="^\d{3}\d{3}\d{4}$" maxlength="10"  minlength="10"  required >
```

However that doesn't limit to only numbers and only one format works i want to do something like:

```
<input name="Phone" type="number"  class="form-control"     placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="10"  minlength="10"     required="required"/>
```

and that code does not limit the max and min lengths!
How do I get the lengths to work?
I know this code works:

```
 <input name="Example" type="text"  class="form-control"     placeholder="Example input" maxlength="10"  minlength="10"     required="required"/>
```

But that's text not numbers!

Comment: How about using a pattern to enforce accepting only number?
`<input type="text" pattern="\d+" maxlength="10" minlength="10" required/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using pattern "\d+" to enforce this on the input?

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d+" maxlength="10" minlength="10" required/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works perfect as I wanted!!!